# Wi-Fi not working with bluetooth device connected on Asus Zenbook UX5401ZA

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, asus

I have an ASUS Zenbook 14X UX5401ZA laptop, it comes with a Mediatek 7922 wifi card. Currently, I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 with the default kernel (5.15.0-52-generic) and the network connection is unstable, it loses connection and works terribly slow with Bluetooth devices connected.

I tried multiple installations of Ubuntu 20.04.5 or Ubuntu 22.04.1 and either Bluetooth did not work at all (Bluetooth adapter not detected) or network connection did not work when Bluetooth devices were connected or Bluetooth did not detect some devices (keyboard and mouse, while it detected other computers/TVs/smartphones).

I saw this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1970923, but installing the newest proposed `linux-firmware` version did not fix the issue. I also tried 5.19.17 kernel with no luck.

Both wifi and Bluetooth work perfectly on Windows, so it's not a hardware problem.

Did anyone manage to make this laptop/wifi card work with Ubuntu?

Comment: An actual kernel version would help. In a terminal run uname -a after edit the question and add the info.

Comment: Right, I added the kernel version

Answer (score 0):

I have also an ASUS 5401ZA.
With Ubuntu Mate 22.04.1 the wifi works fine but the bluetooth no.
After updating to 22.10 Kinetic with kernel 5.19.0-29-generic everything work fine.
Also work all Fn keys except Fn+F10 for camera on-off.

:)